# New modules view depends on Application module

Tags: zend-framework2

I create a new module on ZendSkeletonApplication But when i delete the module "Application" there is an error because of new modules views depends on the "layout.phtml" file in "Application", How can i remove this dependence ?

Answer (score 1):

We often move all view logic from the Application file into a module called Template. Any 3rd party module you use can have templates and we consolidate all templates (layouts + 3rd party overridden view scripts) in a template module.